# Trying to understand if loop output and return function

Tags: python

I solving the vanity plates problem from CS50 online class. I writing first part of code to check that the plate number is not less then 2 characters and not more then 6. The issue is that I am getting confused by the output of if statement.

```
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(s):
    if len(s) < 2 or len(s) > 6:
        return False
    return True
main()
```

When running this code it gives me the correct output.

```
$ python plates.py
Plate: AAA520
Valid
$ python plates.py
Plate: AAAAAA5236
Invalid
```

However, when I do not include "return True" I always get "Invalid".

How is that is_valid function does not automatically return True in the case that input is more then 2 and less then 6 character and why do we need that return True? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't explicitly `return` a value, a function's result is `None` - which is "falsy" in a boolean context, just like `False` is.

Comment: Thanks this makes some much more sense! Thank you!